# Angular KARMA with Jasmine + JEST or JASMINE + JEST, both same project

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine

how I can configure dual configuration in Angular 15 to use Karma with Jasmine + Jest. Or Jasmine + JEST?

When I use that configuration "error TS2315: Type "Spy" is not generic". appears. Another error "Cannot find module 'src/app/core/services/http.service' form 'src/......./chuldren.component.spect.ts' appears.

I am using this instructions but not working https://gannimet.medium.com/migrating-a-large-angular-project-from-jasmine-to-jest-incrementally-52cfd846333b

Thanks!